# Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll needs to be included in Project

Tags: c#, oracle

From the oracle website, it states that we don't need to reference Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll,

[Installing Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/installODPmd.htm#ODPNT8152)

For my project, it throws exception when I didn't put the dll inside my Bin directory.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I set Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll 'Copy Local' = true...

Anything that I miss out?

I am using oracle 12c client 32 bits in windows 7 64 bits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll is (or should be) necessary only if you're using distributed transactions. However, if you're using System.Transactions to manage your database transactions, your transactions may be getting promoted to distributed transactions automatically.

You may be able to turn this behavior off by adding
    enlist=false
to your existing connection string.